# How to cancel multiparts uploading file inbetween ios(how to cancel background thread)

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, image-uploading, multipartform-data

hello i am using this code to upload an image to server by multiparts format. and everything working file. But according to my requirement if the image data is heavy(large) then i want to cancel the uploading in between.

My Code is

```
 NSString *imagePostUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/users/%@/profilepic",Kwebservices,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"l_userid"]];
//
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"profilePic%ld%c%c.png", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970], arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a', arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a'];


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.url"]];


NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"":@""};
AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[manager setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:imagePostUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imagedata name:fileName fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];


} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);

    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imagestr1];
    imageViewProfile.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]];

    [kappDelegate HideIndicator];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);

    [HelperAlert alertWithOneBtn:AlertTitle description:@"Failed to upload selected profile picture" okBtn:OkButtonTitle];

    [kappDelegate HideIndicator];

    return ;
}];
[op start];
```

how can i stop uploading process in middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a reference to the operation and call the `NSOperation` method `cancel`.

For more information on how to handle this:

- [Cancel method reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOperation/cancel)
- [Responding to the cancel command](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591-RH2-SW18)

**Steps:**

1. Declare the property: `@property (strong, nonatomic) AFHTTPRequestOperation *imagePostOperation;`
2. Replace the declaration of your protperty inside your code with `self.imagePostOperation = [manager POST:imagePostUrl ...`
3. When you want to cancel the operation: `[self.imagePostOperation cancel]`
4. In the operation succes/failure callback blocks, check `[operation isCancelled]` to manage that case.

Comment: thanks for the response....can you provide the code how should i cancel the request from button click and how can get the canceled request status......as i am not able to much understand the apple documents.

Comment: @ParvBhasker I updated the answer with some steps that should be easy to follow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[(AFHTTPRequestOperationManager*)manager.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
```

Comment: thanks for the response....should i have to run this code in the cancel button action and it will terminate the image uploading.....?